# "GF(2)-like" field with addition operation defined by OR instead of XOR

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

For an application I'm working on, I'm interested in using a field that has all the properties of the finite Galois field GF(2). For reference, the addition operation $+$ in GF(2) is defined by:

$$
\begin{array}{c c|c}
  A & B & A+B \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

which in digital logic is referred to as exclusive-OR (XOR) and is sometimes denoted $A \oplus B$. The appeal of using a field such as GF(2) is that all the standard results from linear algebra can be applied to vectors and matrices defined over this field.

Is there a comparable algebraic structure that exists with all of the same operations defined on its elements (of which there are also only two-- $0$ and $1$) except that $+$ is defined as the OR operation rather than XOR? In other words, the truth table would be given by:

$$
\begin{array}{c c|c}
  A & B & A+B \\\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
If such a structure exists, would it also be considered a field? Will it posses the "usual" properties such that it can be used in operations in a vector space?

Comment: This operation has an identity, but it has no inverses: it is not a group.

Comment: 0 is the identity element, but only 0 has an inverse. This is a semigroup, and so cannot be the additive structure of a field.

Comment: With OR and AND you get what is known as a lattice (add NOT to the mix, and you have a boolean algebra). Unfortunately you lose the tools of linear algebra. This shows right away when you look at linear equations. For example the equation $1 \operatorname{OR} x=1$ has two solutions, $x=0$ and $x=1$, whereas the equation $1 \operatorname{OR} x=0$ has no solutions. In a system where linear algebra holds such an equation always has a unique solution. I'm sure quite a bit is known about finding solutions of systems of `linear' equations in a boolean algebra, but the theory is necessarily different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I acknowledge that this question was answered in the comments; I am posting as an answer here for completeness.)

Such a structure exists by the simple fact that you have defined it, but it is not a field.

Every field has an additive inverse.  In this case that means that $0+x=0$ and $1+x=0$ must both have solutions.  This can be checked in your table.  The first equation has a solution (in fact, your sum has an additive identity).  But inspection of the table shows that the second equation does not have a solution.  Since there is no additive inverse, the structure you propose is not a field.